# How to detect which checkboxes in row are checked, which aren't

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I have a table with couple of rows. Each row has 6 checkboxes. I know how to count checked checkboxes for each row but don't know how to determine which of them are checked and which aren't inside each row, like:

1. row: 1,1,1,0,0,0
2. row: 0,0,0,0,1,1 ...

I tried some code but not worthy to show it here.

Comment: May be you can name your check boxes based on the row.

Comment: Please, provide your code so we can help you debug it.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: I did it, why negative vote, I'm beginner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the 0's and 1's you can easily use jQuery's map() method to get the state of the checkboxes in each row.

```js
var table = $("table tbody")  // reference the table
table.on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {  // listen for checkbox being checked
  var result = table.find("tr")  // find the table rows
    .map( function () {  // loop over to create an array of the rows
      return $(this).find("input:checkbox")  // find the checkboxes in the row
        .map(function () {    // loop over and create array of the checkbox state
          return this.checked ? "1" : "0"  // if checked it is 1, else 0
        }).get().join("")  // change the array into a string of 0 and 1's
    }).get().join("<br/>")  // combine the array lines on the page
  $("#out").html(result)  // display the  result
}).find('input:checkbox:eq(0)').change();  // trigger change on first checkox so code runs
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: Understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it with Javascript without jQuery:

```
var checkboxData = [];
var trs = document.querySelectorAll("#yourtable tr");
for (var tr of trs) {
    var rowCheckboxes = tr.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    checkboxData.push([]);
    for (checkbox of rowCheckboxes) {
        checkboxData[checkboxData.length - 1].push(checkbox.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked");
    }
};
```

With jQuery you do something similar, but with `$("#yourtable tr").each` and `.find()`.

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad, I didn't check your solution, in meantime I made up something but I guess it could be better, with more briefly code, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In meantime I made something what looks like plausible solution, maybe there are better solutions, there is what I did, please correct me with better idea, thanks:

```
function whichCbox() {
   var res='';
   $('#Table2 tr').not(':first').each(function(){
      var hdn = $(this).find('input[id^="Checkbox"]');
      for(var x=0;x<=5;x++){ //there is 6 checkboxes
          if(hdn[x].checked==true) {
              res+='1';
              } else{
              res+='0';
          }
      }
      console.log('State of checkboxes in row is:'+res);
      res='';
   });
return false;
}
```

Comment: well your code is wrong that the console.log will show more than the checkboxes in the row. You would be better off with map()

Comment: I tried and works fine, no more checkbox indicators per row than need it

Comment: It is going to be first line: `State of checkboxes in row is:00000` and the second log would be `State of checkboxes in row is:0000000000` because res is not reset

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like youre using jQuery you could do the following:

```
   var countBoxes = function(){
      const result = [];
      var $rows = $(document).find("tr"); //demo purpose, normally you would pass this as a param 
        $rows.each(function(i, elem){
         result.push({row: i+1, amount: $(elem).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length}); 
      });

      console.log(result) //=>          {row: 1, amount: 1}
                                    //  {row: 2, amount: 1}
                                    //  {row: 3, amount: 2}
                                    //  {row: 4, amount: 1}
}
```

It simply loops through all the rows () and checks for inputs of type checkbox that are checked(:checked).